# My sql transaction to transfer 1000 from one account to another account in a single table account(name,balance)

Tags: mysql, transactions

My SQL transaction to transfer 1000 from one account to another account in a single table account(name, balance)?

I wrote below query, I am not sure how to check conditions.

```
START TRANSACTION

UPDATE account SET balance = balance - 100 WHERE name = 'D'

UPDATE account SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE name = 'A'

COMMIT
```

how to check conditions for sufficient amount before transfer ?

Comment: just to answer  your logic :) if balance - amount >=0 then perform something if not fail!!

Answer (score 6):

Use a stored procedure to define the transaction:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sample_balance_transfer $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sample_balance_transfer ()
BEGIN

  DECLARE balance_var INT DEFAULT 0;

  SELECT IFNULL(balance,0)
  INTO   balance_var
  FROM   account
  WHERE  name = 'D';

  IF balance_var >= 1000 THEN
    START TRANSACTION;

      UPDATE account
      SET balance = balance - 1000
      WHERE name = 'D';

      UPDATE account
      SET balance = balance + 1000
      WHERE name = 'A';

    COMMIT;
  END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then execute the stored proc:

```
CALL sample_balance_transfer();
```

Note - may want to added exit handler for errors

Comment: Thanks , but I want do do it with transaction... with conditions .. is it possible ?